# Battery FullChargeCapacity using WMI returns 0

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, wmi, battery

I tried using WMI in C++. In the WMI class `CIM_Battery`, `FullChargeCapacity` value just returns 0.

Is there any other method to get `FullChargeCapacity`?

The code I tried is:

```
IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
ULONG uReturn = 0;

while (pEnumerator)
{
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1,
        &pclsObj, &uReturn);

    if (0 == uReturn)
    {
        break;
    }

    VARIANT vtProp;

    // Get the value of the Name property


    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"FullChargeCapacity", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    wcout << " FullChargeCapacity  : " << vtProp.ulVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);
    /*hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    wcout << " Name  : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
    VariantClear(&vtProp);*/

    pclsObj->Release();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you figured out yourself, with WMI you will not get the information you want, you'll have to talk with the battery driver directly.

The battery driver communicates with the battery over I²C and has access to these values. Luckily, there are some battery specific IOCLT codes you can use.

You first need to know the *deviceName* of the battery's driver. Below method uses SetupApi for that, but you could also get it from the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACKINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CmBatt\Enum\0` (assuming your battery uses the *CmBatt.sys* driver). I do recommend using SetupApi.

Below is a helper function to get the *deviceName*:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <SetupAPI.h>
#include <batclass.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef UNICODE
typedef std::string String;
#else
typedef std::wstring String;
#endif

const String GetBatteryDevicePath(const int batteryIndex)
{
    String result = TEXT("");
    HDEVINFO hDeviceInfoList = ::SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_BATTERY, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    if (hDeviceInfoList != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA did = { 0 };
        did.cbSize = sizeof(did);
        if (::SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDeviceInfoList, 0, &GUID_DEVCLASS_BATTERY, batteryIndex, &did))
        {
            DWORD dwRequiredSize = 0;
            ::SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDeviceInfoList, &did, 0, 0, &dwRequiredSize, 0);
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
            {
                PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pdidd = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)::LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwRequiredSize);
                if (pdidd)
                {
                    pdidd->cbSize = sizeof(*pdidd);
                    if (::SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDeviceInfoList, &did, pdidd, dwRequiredSize, &dwRequiredSize, 0))
                    {
                        result = pdidd->DevicePath;
                    }

                    ::LocalFree(pdidd);
                }
            }
        }

        ::SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDeviceInfoList);
    }

    return result;
}
```

After that, you can open a handle to the battery device using [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
const String devicePath = ::GetBatteryDevicePath(0);

const auto hBattery = ::CreateFile(devicePath.c_str(),
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
    NULL);
```

Now we need the battery [*tag*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372659(v=vs.85).aspx), this is an identifier for the battery generated by the driver. F.e. if you swap batteries, the driver will generate a new tag. With this tag we can query the rest of the battery information (see [BATTERY_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372661(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
if (hBattery != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DWORD dwBytesReturned, dwWait = 0;
    BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION bqi = { 0 };
    // Query battery tag
    if (::DeviceIoControl(hBattery,
            IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_TAG,
            &dwWait,
            sizeof(dwWait),
            &bqi.BatteryTag,
            sizeof(bqi.BatteryTag),
            &dwBytesReturned,
            NULL)
        && bqi.BatteryTag)
    {
        // Now we can query all other battery info
        BATTERY_INFORMATION bi = { 0 };
        if (::DeviceIoControl(hBattery,
                IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION,
                &bqi,
                sizeof(bqi),
                &bi,
                sizeof(bi),
                &dwBytesReturned,
                NULL))
        {
            std::cout << "FullChargedCapacity = " << bi.FullChargedCapacity << std::endl;
            std::cout << "DesignedCapacity = " << bi.DesignedCapacity << std::endl;
        }
    }

    ::CloseHandle(hBattery);
}
```

IOCTL codes and related structs are outlined on [MSDN Power Management Control Codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373156(v=vs.85).aspx)

**UPDATE**

As requested in your comment, for reading out the time estimation, request the tag in `bqi` as in the previous snippet, then query `BatteryEstimatedTime` like this:

```
bqi.AtRate = 0;
bqi.InformationLevel = BatteryEstimatedTime;
ULONG lEstimatedTime;
if (::DeviceIoControl(hBattery,
        IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION,
        &bqi,
        sizeof(bqi),
        &lEstimatedTime,
        sizeof(lEstimatedTime),
        &dwBytesReturned,
        NULL))
{
    if (lEstimatedTime != BATTERY_UNKNOWN_TIME)
        std::cout << "EstimatedTime = " << lEstimatedTime / 60 << "m" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "EstimatedTime = UNKNOWN" << std::endl;
}
```

For reading out the actual voltage and capacity:

```
BATTERY_WAIT_STATUS bws = { 0 };
BATTERY_STATUS bs = { 0 };
bws.BatteryTag = bqi.BatteryTag;
if (::DeviceIoControl(hBattery,
    IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_STATUS,
    &bws,
    sizeof(bws),
    &bs,
    sizeof(bs),
    &dwBytesReturned,
    NULL))
{
    if (bs.PowerState & BATTERY_CHARGING)
        std::cout << "Battery is CHARGING" << std::endl;
    if (bs.PowerState & BATTERY_DISCHARGING)
        std::cout << "Battery is DISCHARGING" << std::endl;
    if (bs.PowerState & BATTERY_POWER_ON_LINE)
        std::cout << "Power on-line" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Battery voltage: " << bs.Voltage << "mV" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Battery capacity: " << bs.Capacity << "mW" << std::endl;
}
```

By comparing `bs.Capacity` against the `bi.FullChargedCapacity` you can get a percentage indication of the remaining capacity of the battery.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!!
I merge all of code you wrote but compiler notice me 4 error one of them is :
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces@20 referenced in function "class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const __cdecl GetBatteryDevicePath(int)"
How could I do?

Comment: You must link with SetupApi.lib

Comment: Oh my God...You have awesome skill!!
then can I also know charging rate , EstimatedChargeRemaining or current amount of battery??
I tried :
BATTERY_QUERY_INFORMATION bqi = { 3, BatteryEstimatedTime };
   std::cout << bqi.AtRate;
//It return 0
AND
//
BATTERY_STATUS bi = { 3 };
    if (::DeviceIoControl(hBattery,
     IOCTL_BATTERY_QUERY_STATUS,
     &bqi,
     sizeof(bqi),
     &bi,
     sizeof(bi),
     &dwBytesReturned,
     NULL))
    {std::cout << bi.Rate << std::endl;
//It didn't work

Comment: updated my answer, when using an IOCTLs and structures documented on MSDN, be sure to read every detail :)

Comment: I tried and It worked well !! 
 I'm deeply greatful. you save me
where did you get this amazing skill?? I'm impressed...

Comment: Well few years ago I had to develop a battery minidriver for a custom battery on Windows. Since there is near to zero documentation for that on internet, I had to read all details and use IRP sniffing to figure it out. Don't forget to mark it as an answer please :)

Comment: Wow that’s a lot of help to not get an upvote or marked as solution.

Comment: I appreciate your comment @DougMaurer 