# Trying to get FullChargeCapacity from Win32_PortableBattery Class

Tags: powershell, class, get-wmiobject

I'm trying to get full charge capacity of remote notebook battery info in our company, but it returns empty output when I run the code. I did some googling and I know I need to ask the driver of the battery for the info (can be found in registry too I think), but I have weak programming skills and have no idea how to do it. I am also doing `DesignCapacity` instead of `FullChargeCapacity` at the end of the code, and this one works. Can anyone help me? Thank you

My code:

```
$NTB_Battery_ActualCapacity = $(Get-WmiObject win32_portablebattery -Computername $remote_PC).FullChargeCapacity
```

Comment: With"*weak programming skills*", this wouldn't be easy. See [Battery FullChargeCapacity using WMI returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34056927/battery-fullchargecapacity-using-wmi-returns-0) for the `C#` answer/solution...

Comment: i've removed the powershell-ise tag as well as change the title because powershell-ise is completely irrelevant in this case

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt with powercfg.

```
powercfg /batteryreport /xml

Battery life report saved to file path C:\Users\admin\battery-report.xml.


[xml]$xml = get-content battery-report.xml
$xml.BatteryReport.Batteries.Battery


Id                 : Primary
Manufacturer       : Hewlett-Packard
SerialNumber       : 12345 2018/04/13
ManufactureDate    :
Chemistry          : LIon
LongTerm           : 1
RelativeCapacity   : 0
DesignCapacity     : 44357
FullChargeCapacity : 44357
CycleCount         : 0


$xml.BatteryReport.Batteries.Battery.FullChargeCapacity

44357
```

Comment: thanks, can you help me to implement this code to my code - for remote pc? I am trying to do it but without luck

Comment: I would run it with invoke-command.